# Can't find the root of this vba object oriented error

Tags: vba, excel

I developed a simple code that graphs the temperature distribution in a plain wall for uni dimensional heat equation, it looks something like this:

[image: T(x)]

by refining the time value a better approximation of the problem for steady state is obtained. The problem is that if I enter a `j > 15000` I get an application oriented error and i don't know how to fix this.

Code looks like this:

```
Sub wi_ins()

Dim wall, ds, results As Worksheet
Dim i As Integer
Dim T, j, jota As Double

Set wall = Sheets("WITH INSULATOR")
Set ds = Sheets("DATA SPREAD 2")
Set results = Sheets("RESULTS 2")

ds.UsedRange.ClearContents

With ds
    Lw = wall.Cells(20, 9).Value
    Li = wall.Cells(19, 13).Value
    n = wall.Cells(19, 9).Value
    n2 = wall.Cells(18, 13).Value

    Text = wall.Cells(22, 9).Value
    Tint = wall.Cells(23, 9).Value

    jota = wall.Cells(14, 20).Value

    .Range(.Cells(1, 1), .Cells(n - 1, 1)).Value = Text
    .Range(.Cells(n, 1), .Cells(n + n2 - 1, 1)).Value = Text

    .Range(.Cells(1, 1), .Cells(1, jota)).Value = Text ' <--- //this is where the error appears
    .Cells((n - 1 + n2), 1).Value = Tint
    '... rest of code below
```

As you can see I simply take j and paste `T.ext` within a range. if "jota" is bigger than 15000 it just won't work

Comment: first you need to define your objects and variables correctly, it should be `Dim wall as Worksheet, ds As Worksheet, results As Worksheet` and `Dim T As Double, j As Double, jota As Double`. Otherwise, `wall`, `ds`, `T`, `j` are `Variant`s. Second, you should define `j As Long`, and I think also `T` and `jota` `As Long. And **Third** where do you define and set `Text` in your code, you also better not use a reserved Excel word, instead maybe use `myText`

Comment: You're using *jota* as a column index number in ....Cells(1, jota)... There are only 16,384 possible columns on a worksheet.

Comment: well that explains it... i really need those extra columns :(

Comment: What's value in `wall.Cells(14, 20)`? If it is blank, that will throw an error as the column index cannot be 0.

Comment: Since there are much more rows then columns in a Worksheet, then you may want to “transpose” your cells layout: have jota span through rows and n and n2 through columns